# I cannot add 'null' in foreign key

Tags: mysql, sql, null, foreign-keys

I have created two tables, as shown below:

```
CREATE TABLE `leiame` (
    `id` INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `number` INT(10) NOT NULL,
    `title` VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`) )

CREATE TABLE `download` (
    `id` INT(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `name` VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
    `id_leiame` INT(10) UNSIGNED NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
    CONSTRAINT `leia_id_fk` FOREIGN KEY (`id_leiame`) 
                            REFERENCES `leiame` (`id`) ON UPDATE CASCADE )
```

When I add a **null** value for id_leiame on download, the following error occurs:

> Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`bd`.`download`, CONSTRAINT `leia_id_fk` FOREIGN KEY (`id_leiame`) REFERENCES `leiame` (`id`) ON UPDATE CASCADE)

I set the id_leiame as NULL.

What I am missing?

Comment: [Works for me](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a6343/1). Can you post the DML that's causing the issue?

Comment: are you sure your insert is correct ... and you don't try to insert 'null' instead of null.  insert into kkm.download (name, id_leiame) values ('something', null);    works fine on my machine :-)

Comment: I insert 'null' but don't work!
DML code:
$crud = new crud('download');
$crud->inserir("name,id_leiame", "'$name','$leiame'");

Comment: you should insert null ... not 'null'

Comment: If I insert something in id_leiame, that's correct! Don't occurs errors!!! And if I insert 'null' in id_leiame, error occurs! What I am missing?

Comment: $leiame = null;
$crud->inserir("name,id_leiame", "'$name','$leiame'");

Comment: @Marcel: Please add your code in the question as this seems to be the cause of the issue, the difference between NULL as a special value and 'null' as a string.

Comment: I have tried to add NULL, but the error occurs.
The attribute id_leiame, in download, is populated in a combobox. If I don't select any id_leiame, the error occurs.

Comment: Please show all relevant code. [mcve] Please explain cleary. Eg we don't know what "add a null value for id_leiame on download" means in terms of code. Please edit your question, don't respond with clarifications in comments.

Answer (score 0):

As others pointed out in the comments, based on the statement you're executing, you seem to insert 'null' (i.e. a string containing null) instead of actual NULL, i.e. the absence of a value.

What you need to do is something along the lines of (*not* proper syntax)

```
if($leiame == "")
   $crud->inserir("name,id_leiame", "'$name',null") << no single quotes!
else
   $crud->inserir("name,id_leiame", "'$name','$leiame'")
```

Comment: Could you provide the exact statement?

Comment: <label>Leia-me</label>
<select name="leiaID" style="width:228px;">
<option value="<?php echo $id ?>">Waiting...</option>
</select>

$leiame = $_POST['leiaID'];
$crud->inserir("name,id_leiame", "'$name','$leiame'");

Comment: I mean the one where you explicitly put in NULL instead of 'null'. Or did you just try inserting 'NULL' (i.e. still a string, but uppercase)!?

Comment: I tried but didn't work! =( 
The error is: Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`bd`.`download`, CONSTRAINT `leia_id_fk` FOREIGN KEY (`id_leiame`) REFERENCES `leiame` (`id`) ON UPDATE CASCADE)

Comment: The error is clear. The *cause* is not clear. From all the code you provided so far it seems you're always inserting a string containing the characters 'n' 'u' 'l' 'l, never the actual null value, hence the FK error, since that string does not exist in the table leiname table. What you need to do is something along the lines of ‘if($leiname == '') INSERT NULL else INSERT $leiname‘. (I cannot give you the PHP code since I don't know PHP well enough)